# How to skip a value inside Vue loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to skip value "Three" from the loop (from following code)

```
<script >
  const routes = [
    {name: 'One', value: 24},
    {name: 'Two', value: 25},
    {name: 'Three', value: 26},
    {name: 'Four', value: 34},
  ]
  export default {
    name: 'App',
    computed: {
      routes(){
        return routes;
      }
    },
  } 
</script>

<template>  
  <div id="app">
    <div class="movies">
      <h2>Which movie?</h2>      
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(route in routes" >
          <span v-if="route.name !== 'Three'">{{ route.name }}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

The above code renders something like:

[image]

So basically the "li" tag is added but empty.

If I move the v-if in the "v-for" like this:

```
<template>  
  <div id="app">
    <div class="movies">
      <h2>Which movie?</h2>      
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(route in routes" v-if="route.name !== 'Three'">
          <span>{{ route.name }}</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I get this error:
[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: This topic is covered in the docs here: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#displaying-filtered-sorted-results

Answer (score 4):

Try to remove 3 in computed property:

```js
const routes = [
  {name: 'One', value: 24},
  {name: 'Two', value: 25},
  {name: 'Three', value: 26},
  {name: 'Four', value: 34},
]
new Vue({
  el: "#demo",
  computed: {
    routes(){
      return routes.filter(r => r.name !== "Three");
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo"> 
  <div class="movies">
    <h2>Which movie?</h2>      
    <ul>
      <li v-for="route in routes" >
        <span>{{ route.name }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah...but I wanted to see if I can use the v-for and v-if. I feel that by doing it like this is "cheating Vue" :)

Comment: @Alex  hey mate :) why cheating? If you want to show filtered data then , in my opinion, best way is to prepare data first. Avoid operation on data in template . cheers :)

Comment: I agree with you that that filtering saves the day but I didn't explain the problem,only avoid it, which can be ok when you are in a hurry. I was baffled by the fact that v-for combined with v-if triggers those weird behavior...but now (see my answer) it's clear.

Answer (score 2):

What about filtering your routes in the `v-for` directive?

```html
<li v-for="route in routes.filter(r => r.name !== 'Three')" >
```

You could also use a computed property for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1249641/marco)'s link (from comment) I discovered this information https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#v-for-with-v-if and based on it I was able to do something like:

```
<template>  
  <div id="app">
    <div class="movies">
      <h2>Which movie?</h2>      
      <ul>
        <template v-for="route in routes">
          <li v-if="route.name !== 'Four'">
            <span>{{ route.name }}</span>
          </li>  
        </template>        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is pretty "Vue like" and also no more errors (due to precedence of v-if over v-for)